# i want to remove the search bar from the right column in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

i want to remove the search bar and the advanced search link in the right side bar.i tried using the local.xml to remove the advanced search link and the search box but nothing happens. Iam working on a local server (wamp).there is no mention of the search box in the menu.phtml also and the bolg extension used is aw blog extension

site currently looks like this

[image: site currently looks like this.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to turn on template path hints in admin (Configuration->System->Developer in Debug tab) so you can locate phtml witch is displaying block that you need to remove. With that name you can find it in xml and remove it by name.